# How do you call a MySQL procedure with parameters?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, stored-procedures, parameters

I am trying to call a stored procedure when I click a button in a winform. The stored procedure has an insert statement where the value `boardID = @newGameID`.

`newGameID` references a value that is passed in in my c# code. As a test I have made that value 1. Here is my stored procedure:

```
delimiter //
create procedure loopData()
BEGIN
DECLARE i int DEFAULT 0;
WHILE i <= 62 DO
INSERT INTO tbl_tile (boardID) VALUES(@newGameID);
SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;
END//
delimiter ;
```

And here is my c# code that is linked to the button:

```
private void Tile()
{
    var connectionString = "server=localhost;password=1234;user id=root;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=dat602_assessmentdb_m2"; 
    using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("loopData", connection);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("newGameID", 1);
        command.Connection.Open();
        var result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        command.Connection.Close();
    }

}
```

When I run the winform, I get this error:

[image: Error Message]

I'm not sure if I have structured this correctly, but I would have thought that when I do `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("newGameID", 1)`, it would set the parameter value in the stored procedure to 1. How might I fix this or is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a good questions, but rather than posting a link to a screenshot of the error it would be helpful to transcribe it into your question. That makes it a lot easier for people to read and answer your question

Comment: Don't you need to declare the parameter when you create the stored procedure?  CREATE PROCEDURE loopData(IN newGameId int)

Comment: sorry @KevinWells, I need 10 rep to insert the picture

Comment: Ill try that @NicholasHunter

Comment: It still returns the same error when I do `delimiter //
create procedure loopData(IN newGameId int)
BEGIN
DECLARE i int DEFAULT 0;
WHILE i <= 62 DO
INSERT INTO tbl_tile (boardID) VALUES(@newGameID);
SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;
END//
delimiter ;`

Comment: @Travis123 Sorry for the misunderstanding, I was actually trying to suggest typing it out rather than using an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the sql stored procedure that you invoke, does not have any parameters! The stored procedure does refer to a **session variable** within its body, but that's not part of the sql statement your are passing.

You should change the stored procedure to have a parameter and then you can pass it the way you do:

```
delimiter //
create procedure loopData(IN newGameID int)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE i int DEFAULT 0;
        WHILE i <= 62 DO
            INSERT INTO tbl_tile (boardID) VALUES(newGameID);
            SET i = i + 1;
        END WHILE;
    END//
delimiter ;
```

You can now use your c# code to pass a parameter to your stored procedure.

Warning: my solution fixes the error message in the question only! The body of the stored procedure does not make too much sense to me, as it is trying to insert the passed value 63 times into tbl_title table. If this field is the primary key as its name suggests, then you will get an duplicate key error whenever you invoke this stored procedure. Fixing this is beyond the scope of this question as there is no information how this should work and the question was not about a duplicate key error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newGameID", 1)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Eder. Could you expand on this answer by describing what your code is supposed to do and how it answers the question?

Comment: try this way, If you get the same error, check your SP

            string Conn = "server=localhost;password=1234;user id=root;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=dat602_assessmentdb_m2"
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Conn);

            try
            {
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("loopData", con);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newGameID", 1);

                con.Open();
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();


            }

Comment: I tried this but it still returns the same error. The SP string is correct as it has been used elsewhere. The stored procedure works if I set it with a value of one in the database, but if I want to create a parameter, it doesn't work

Comment: What I mean is that the stored procedure works when I do `INSERT INTO tbl_tile (boardID) VALUES(1);`. But I want value to be a parameter

Comment: when you create your Procedure, you declare the @NewGameID??

I mean this

create procedure loopData
 @newGameID int
AS
BEGIN 

...

END

Answer (score 0):

This can help for someone.

MySQL procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `bestSellingProducts`(IN startDate DATETIME, IN endDate DATETIME, IN nTop INT)
    BEGIN
    SELECT p.product_id, p.product_name, p.price
        FROM orders o 
        INNER JOIN order_items oi ON oi.order_id = o.order_id
        INNER JOIN products p ON p.product_id=oi.product_id
        WHERE (o.order_date BETWEEN startDate AND endDate)
        GROUP BY p.product_id
        ORDER BY quantitySold DESC
        LIMIT nTop;
    END
```

Now how to use with C#/VB

```
command.CommandText = "dbname.bestSellingProducts"
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startDate", fromDate)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endDate", toDate)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nTop", 10)
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
```

Notes.
For this example fromDate and toDate are DateTime types.
Is good to use Try/Catch when open connection.

Answer (score -1):

try this way, If you get the same error, check your SP

```
        string Conn = "server=localhost;password=1234;user id=root;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=dat602_assessmentdb_m2"
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Conn);

        try
        {
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("loopData", con);
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newGameID", 1);

            con.Open();
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();


        }
```

Comment: It says it requires a catch since you are doing try

Comment: try {

}Catch(Ex)
{

}

Comment: SqlConnection and SqlCommand classes are for ms sql server. The question is about mysql.

Comment: Dude, the same structure, only change SQLCommand for MYSQLCommand when you declare  com.

Comment: Dude, it's not going to work even then either.